# Java inheritance: Is there a way to specify that only one of two methods must be overridden

Tags: java, inheritance

For some derived classes, I want to ensure that one of two overloaded abstract methods gets overridden, but not both. Is this possible?

```
abstract void move();
abstract void move(int x, int y);
```

There is an abstract particle class that is extended by several classes. One of the derived classes receives mouse input to calculate its movement, while the others do not. All of the derived classes have a move function. What is a good way to go about coding the inheritance for this?

Comment: +1 for Femaref. Something wrong with design.

Comment: I second the call for a review of your architecture design. In the particular case you bring up it is better to have the concrete implementation that needs mouse input get it itself than to pass mouse coordinates to all implementations.

Comment: Used static fields and a set method that is called once per frame, while separately implementing the abstract no args method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Java requires that all `abstract` methods be implemented by concrete subclasses.

Leave the decision of whether the parameters should be ignored to the callee, not the caller. Take for example a hypothetical 3D rendering system with multiple rendering engines:

```
abstract class Renderer {
  boolean isPointVisible(int x, int y);
}

class SimpleRenderer {
  @Override
  public boolean isPointVisible(int x, int y) {
    return true;
  }
}

class ComplexRenderer {
  @Override
  public boolean isPointVisible(int x, int y) {
    return x > 0 && x < 100 && y < 0 && y < 100;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No. But if you explain why you want to do it then may be there are other options.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible, as it would break polymorphism rules. You should rethink your architecture, as this is severe code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Given a number of strategies can alter the state of the particle it seems the responsibility of moving it should be external to the particle itself. It seems like the particle should itself be a simple concrete class which holds state information (i.e. position, etc), whilst at runtime you can determine which strategy will operate on changing the particle's state.